# How can I pass an array of matrices to a VertexShader

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenGL but I'm having problems trying to pass an array of matrices to my VertexShader. I think the problem is in the VertexShader because it seems the values in modelvalue are passed correctly to the components of model, but for some reason at the end only one of the three cubes I've created is drawn. Here's the Main code.

```
glm::mat4 model[3];
GLint ModelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(MyShader.program, "model");
vector<GLfloat> modelvalue;
const int n = int(sizeof(model[0]) / sizeof(GLfloat));

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    model[i] = glm::translate(model[i], cubePositions[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        modelvalue.push_back(glm::value_ptr(model[i])[j]);
    }

}
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelLocation, 3, GL_FALSE, &modelvalue[0]);
```

The VertexShader:

```
   #version 400 core
  layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
  layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
  out vec2 TexCoord;
  out vec4 position0;
  out vec4 position1;
   out vec4 position2;
  uniform mat4 model[3];
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  void main()
  {   
  position0 = projection * view * model[0] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
  position1 = projection * view * model[1] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
  position2 = projection * view * model[2] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
  TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x,1-texCoord.y);
   }
```

And the FragmentShader:

```
  #version 400 core

  layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
  layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;


  out vec2 TexCoord;
  out vec4 position0;
  out vec4 position1;
  out vec4 position2;
  uniform mat4 model[3];
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  void main()
  {   
  position0 = projection * view * model[0] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
  position1 = projection * view * model[1] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
  position2 = projection * view * model[2] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
  TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x,1-texCoord.y);
```

Comment: This is not how you draw 3 cubes.  A vertex shader operates on only **one** vertex at a time; one vertex goes in, one vertex comes out.  To draw 3 cubes you make 3 draw calls, with a different matrix for each.

Comment: You have one cube and each corner of the cube has 3 "positions". And none of those 3 positions are actually used as far as I can tell. I don't know why they're called positions because they are not used as positions; they may as well be called flubbadoodles.

Answer (score 1):

As Le Comte du Merde-fou mentioned in the comment to your question, the purpose of a vertex shader is to perform *per-vertex* operations on an existing single mesh. They cannot generate new geometry, so position1 and position2 will simply be ignored by the primitive assembly stage, as it only accepts the first vertex shader output.

If you wish to render more cubes, you would have to write a geometry shader stage, to generate the new geometry, or duplicate your cpu side render code, using different transform matrices for each one.

I strongly recommend you do some research on the GPU graphics pipeline, and understand what each stage does. Once you do, it will make your life a lot easier.